# how to calculate price using slider [algorithmic problem]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, math

i have a slider that let user chooses betweent 0 and 20000
how to calculate final price with prices per 100 points are like this :

```
from 0 to 1200 -> 2.10$/100pts
from 1200 to 2400 ->2.20$/100pts
from 2400 to 4800 ->2.5$/100pts
from 4800 to 7200 ->3.75$/100pts
from 7200 to 10000 ->5.4$/100pts
from 10000 to 20000 ->10$/100pts
```

**Example :**
user choose from 3000 to 12000
price will be 45$ + 90$ + 151.2 $ + 200 $ => final price will be = 486.2 $

***if you guys can give solution in javascript or i will be fine with algoritmic solution , thanks***

Comment: Are you saying the user chooses *two* values?

Comment: yes sir the user choose two values from 0 to 20000 , in that example he choose 3000 and 12000 so the calculation of the price of that price is 486.2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table with the thresholds and then in JS iterate over it to accumulate the price.

Here is a runnable snippet:

```js
const table = [
    [10000, 10.00],
    [ 7200,  5.40],
    [ 4800,  3.75],
    [ 2400,  2.50],
    [ 1200,  2.20],
    [    0,  2.10],
];

function convert(points) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let [limit, price] of table) {
        if (points > limit) {
             total += Math.floor((points - limit) / 100) * price;
             points = limit;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

// IO handling
let [rngStart, rngEnd] = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let output = document.querySelector("span");
rngStart.addEventListener("input", refresh);
rngEnd.addEventListener("input", refresh);


function refresh() {
    let start = +rngStart.value;
    let end = +rngEnd.value
    output.textContent = (convert(end) - convert(start)).toFixed(2);
}
refresh();
```

```css
input[type=range] { width: 80% }
```

```html
From: <input type="number" min="0" max="20000" step="100" value="3000">
To: <input type="number" min="0" max="20000" step="100" value="12000">

Price: <span></span>
```

Comment: Works like Charm ! Thank you Sir

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm that you can convert to code:

1. Let's have a nested array, or an array of price objects (it's important to be indexable and sorted ascending), for prices called `prices` sorted ascending as follows:

```
[[1200, 2400, 2.2],...]
```

2. Let's have the lower and upper bounds of user input in variables `lower` and `upper`.
3. Let's have a variable `finalPrice` initialized to `0`.
4. Find the index of the first element in prices where its upper bound is > `lower`. Let's call this index `i`.
5. Now run `while lower < upper:`

```
// calc the cost of this range
finalPrice +=  (min(prices[i][1], upper) - lower)/100 * prices[i]
// sets `lower` to the upper bound of the previous price,
// since we already calculated that.
lower = min(prices[i][1], upper) 
// increment i to calc with the next price range
i += 1
```

Since the slider is constraint to 20000 on the upper side, you can be sure that `i` never goes out of bounds.

Comment: thank you sir <3